# How to apply the collider of a prefab to an entity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am using C# in unity and am attempting to apply the sprites and collider of different prefab's to my player entity throughout the game.

The sprite will successfully change, however using a similar script with the collider returns the error "`The left hand side of an assignment must be a variable, property or indexer`" (line 4 here) evoSprite is a Sprite and evoCollider is currently a Collider2D, but I don't think that's right.

Need a way to fix this or an alternative way to do what I want.

Below is the code:

```
    evoSprite = (GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Evo0")[0]).GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite;
    (GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Player")[0]).GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite = evoSprite;
    evoCollider = (GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Evo0")[0]).GetComponent<PolygonCollider2D>();
    (GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Player")[0]).GetComponent<PolygonCollider2D>() = evoCollider;
```

Comment: The left hand side thingy on line #4 is a method. You cannot assign a value to a method.

Comment: I understand this but I am not sure what I should do instead. I want to assign the entire collider of the prefab in place of the primary entitie's one

Comment: Alternative way is to get the size of the sprite and resize the current collider to this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Attention. Thanks everyone for the help, I messed around with the code and have now found the answer. Rather than try to use the entire collider I have discovered that using the code:

```
private evoCollider Vector2;
evoCollider = (GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Evo0")[0]).GetComponent<PolygonCollider2D>().points;
```

Achieves the output I wanted.
Thanks again for the help, and sorry for any inconvenience.

Answer (score 0):

Sprite is an asset reference, and .sprite is a member field/setter, so you are allowed to do component.sprite=newSprite.
However, you are not allowed do do gameobject.colliider = new collider, as collider is not a member of a GameObject instance, its a component.

Consider this: you can have multiple components of the same type on a gameojbect, or none, but one component cannot be linked to multiple gameObjects, which is essentially what you tried to do here.

Use gameobject.AddComponent<>() method to create new instance of the component instead